# How to turn WP https site to http (from secured to non-secured)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I have a simple WP blog that doesn't need https.

My host was offering a free SSL certificate so I took that up.
It's only after that I read that turning a site to https is like having a brand new site and therefore starting SEO all over again.

I've recently moved host and had to use the backups I made to move the content across. I've found out all the internal links on the site are https, probably because the site was secured at the time of making the backup. Unfortunately the browser says my https pages are not secured despite an SSL certificate that seems installed.

Rather than resolving that, I think I will benefit more by turning my site back to http. All my backlinks over the years point to http. So how do I convert all internal links that point to https pages back to http?

All the resources I find online are to turn http to https.

Comment: You need to change the site and home urls in the database table wp_options to the url without https. Then use a plugin to change the media links and anything using your https url to the http url, I recommend Velvet Blues here https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ You also need to redirect all your https urls to the http one, you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: I've updated the site URL in wp_options and used Velvet Blues. It found many URLs to correct but the posts and category links are still https. Image links are now http. 

Did I miss something? I ticked all options in Velvet Blues but the GUID one.

Comment: You need to update both siteurl and home in the wp_options table. You can also try update your permalinks in General > Permalinks and just resave it. Don't forget to do the redirection as Google and other search engines have indexed https for your site.

Comment: There was only siteurl to update, no other https entries in wp_options. However, good point about the permalinks, they all start with https. How do I fix it? I guess it's something to do with the home URL which I cannot find.

Comment: Sorted. I had to display more results in SQL to find the home URL. Updated that and the permalinks got updated too. Easy fix, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: That's great to hear. Please accept my answer :) much appreciated!

Comment: Just a thought: 301 redirects could lose you about 15% of page rank (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Filv4pP-1nw), but https is also a ranking factor and will likely carry more weight in the future. So switching to https could result is a zero sum game, but you would have a secure site. Also it wouldn't say "Not Secure" in the url which, although it is not directly a ranking factor, will turn off some users.

Comment: Agree with you @Rice_Crisp but the user is having issues with their current SSL installation or hosting provider. Hopefully in future they will revert back to https.

Comment: No, for a plain blog, this site will not benefit from https, except on the login page. The latter and the fact that https is the way forward convinced me to switch to a secure site but due to the fact that I start my SEO all over, the gains I make from a secure site are not worth it in this case. I am not bothering with redirecting https links to http for Google as the site hasn't been on https for long and these links don't have much value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Database**
You need to change the site and home urls in the database table wp_options to the url without https.

**Links**
Then use a plugin to change the media links and anything using your https url to the http url, I recommend Velvet Blues here wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls

**Redirection**
You also need to redirect all your https urls to the http one, you can use this plugin wordpress.org/plugins/redirection. As Google and other search engines have indexed https for your site.

**Permalinks**
You can also try update your permalinks in General > Permalinks and just resave it.